# Using nuget packages on machine with no internet

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget

I have a .net core intranet web app which uses certain nuget packages. I have two machines, my local computer with internet and a test machine with no connection to outside internet. The app works fine on my computer.
All the nuget packages are locally stored and referred by the web app.

When I try to build the app on test machine, I am getting the following error

```
 C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100\Nuget.targets(123,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

What process is actually looking for service index from outside url? Of course it cannot find because there is no internet. No proxies involved so nothing to put in nuget.config

All the packages are locally stored. What can I do to resolve this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Have you added a `nuget.config` file to your solution?

Comment: Also when you say "run the app", what do you mean? It looks like you are building and running which is a different thing.

Comment: Sorry I meant build the app :)

Comment: The real question should be how can you get those packages from another source? `NuGet` has to get the packages from *somewhere*. This can be `nuget.org`, a local NuGet server or even a folder, eg a file share or local folder.

Comment: `All the packages are locally stored` if they were, the build wouldn't be trying to restore them. Is there a clean & restore step perhaps?

Comment: @DavidG doesnt the solution automatically uses nuget.config? I have this <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value=".\packages" /> in that file. All the nuget packages are stored in the folder and the entire project is checked in. Wondering if I need to put anything in the solution file?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I dont have VS on test machine. Only .net core sdk and runtime. I will have to see how to clean & restore

Comment: Why are you trying to build on a test machine in the first place? Publish the app and then put the published app on the test machine. The NuGet packages will then be included as DLLs. If you're trying to use the "test" machine as a build server, then it should have outside internet access, as it will need that for all sorts of reasons to properly function as a build server.

Answer (score 4):

1. You’ll need a local folder to keep all your local NuGet packages..
2. Then download the NuGet packages you wish to be able to use offline into this folder. Packages can be downloaded from nuget.org.
3. Once you are logged in, search for the packages you require and click the ‘Download’ link in the left hand menu of each.
4. Once you have successfully downloaded the .nupkg files you require into your local repository folder, head into Visual Studio and open the NuGet Settings dialog via Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Settings. Click the Package Sources tab within the settings dialog, followed by the ‘plus’ icon in the top left to add a new package source.
5. Enter the Name and Source of your local repository. The name can be any string and will be the name displayed in the NuGet Package Manager within Visual Studio.
6. Now that you have added the local package source, you will be able
   to use your offline local repository from within Visual Studio in
   the usual way, either via the Console or via the Package Dialog, by
   selecting it from the Package Source menu, without the need for an active internet connection.